# Does a rest charge on the surface of the earth emit radiation

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation

Suppose we have an observer $O$ in free fall and electric charge $e$ on the surface of the earth. As $O$ is in inertial frame, Maxwell's equations are valid for $O$. However, according to general relativity the electric charge $e$ is accelerated.  Does the observer $O$ see radiation emitted by the charge $e$? Has any experience been made?

Comment: And where do you get the idea the observer would not "see radiation"?

Comment: Has this experience been made?

Comment: I will edit the question

Comment: After looking through some papers I now believe no observer will see radiation at rest in a gravitational field.

Comment: what papers did you look?

Answer (score 0):

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_radiation_of_charged_particles_in_a_gravitational_field#:~:text=The%20paradox%20of%20a%20charge,the%20context%20of%20general%20relativity.&text=Maxwell's%20equations%20say%20that%20an,stationary%20particles%20in%20gravitational%20fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_radiation_of_charged_particles_in_a_gravitational_field#:%7E:text=The%20paradox%20of%20a%20charge,the%20context%20of%20general%20relativity.&text=Maxwell%27s%20equations%20say%20that%20an,stationary%20particles%20in%20gravitational%20fields).

This will answer fully, but quick answer, for a falling object it will observe radiation being emitted from the particle on the ground, but for an observer on the ground it will not observe radiation being emitted from the charged particle on the ground. An observer on the ground will also NOT observe a falling object due to gravity to emit radiation as it is not really accelerating